# update several fields inside react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I want to make a custom field such that if I check an checkbox, then I want to copy a lot of other fields into another set of fields. E.g. if two types of addresses is the same, I do not want the user to have to write it twice. So I have all the logic to make this happen. The only thing I miss is to update the Form such that the validation function will run, inside the `<Form>` from `react-final-form`. Is there a way to just update a lot of values inside this form?

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`form.batch`](https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormApi#batch) is probably what you want. The `FormApi` instance is provided by the `<Form/>` component to [the render prop](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FormRenderProps).

```
<Form onSubmit={submit}>
  {
    ({ handleSubmit, form }) => {
      // here we can do form.batch()
      return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        fields here
      </form>
  }
</Form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I sent down the form.change function and changed my field values like this:

`form.change('nameOfMyField', 'newValueToField')`